# Height parameter in Graphics2D.drawArc

Tags: java, swing, parameters, graphics2d

I'm trying to create an arc, but when I use the same width and height parameters, the arc is almost flat, shouldn't it be higher? I would have expected that the height would appear to be the same length as the width on the screen.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
    g2d.drawArc(0, 0, 100, 100, 45, 90);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
g2d.drawArc(0, 0, 100, 100, 45, 90, Arc2D.CHORD);
```

> I would have expected that the height would appear to be the same length as the width on the screen.

It is because you only draw an arc of 90 degrees. Change the value to 180 and the width/height will be different. Even if you draw 180 the width/height won't be the same. The width/height will only be the same for a 360 degree arc.

Also, what API are you using? Graphics.drawArc(...) only supports 6 parameters, not 7.

Post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) when you ask a question so we can see the behaviour.

Comment: Owh thanks, is there a calculation with the degrees you draw and the height to get the same as the width? And I'm sorry, I use this line of code: Shape arc2D = new Arc2D.Double(xPos, yPos, shipWidth, shipHeight, 45, 90, Arc2D.CHORD); But I wanted to simplify it for this question and forgot to remove the last argument.

Comment: `But I wanted to simplify it for this question and forgot to remove the last argument` - that is why you post a SSCCE, so we know the code is accurate and was tested. I don't know my math, but I would guess something like (0, 90) for the last two parameters. Or maybe (15, 60), The idea of these guesses is that the center of the arc is at 45 degrees. So you could also do this for the other 3 quadrants.

Answer (score 0):

I too have been frustrated with drawArc. [Here's some code I wrote](http://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/ui/util/ShapeUtils.java#l36) to "improve"

```
public static Area createArc(int x, int y, int width, int height, double start, double end, int innerXOffset, int innerYOffset) {
     Shape s = new Ellipse2D.Double(x,y, width, height);
     Area a = new Area(s);
     int center_x = x + width / 2;
     int center_y = y + height / 2;
     int xs[] = new int[6];
     int ys[] = new int[6];
     xs[0] = center_x;
     ys[0] = center_y;
     double middle = start + (end -start) / 2;
     double quarter1 =start + (middle - start)/2; //new point in the polygon between start and middle
     double quarter2 =middle + (end - middle)/2; //new point in the polygon between middle and end

     int pt1_x = (int) (center_x + width * Math.cos(start));
     int pt1_y = (int) (center_y + height * Math.sin(start));
     int pt2_x = (int) (center_x + width * Math.cos(end));
     int pt2_y = (int) (center_y + height * Math.sin(end));
     int mid_x = (int) (center_x + width * Math.cos(middle)); //now there is no need to *2 because with a polygon with 6 points the worst case (360 degrees) is guaranteed
     int mid_y = (int) (center_y + height * Math.sin(middle));
     int quar1_x= (int) (center_x + height * Math.cos(quarter1)); //calculates the x and y for the new points
     int quar1_y= (int) (center_y + height * Math.sin(quarter1));
     int quar2_x= (int) (center_x + height * Math.cos(quarter2));
     int quar2_y= (int) (center_y + height * Math.sin(quarter2));
     //inserts the new points in the polygon' array in the rigth order
     xs[1] = pt1_x;
     ys[1] = pt1_y;
     xs[2] = quar1_x;
     ys[2] = quar1_y;
     xs[3] = mid_x;
     ys[3] = mid_y;
     xs[4] = quar2_x;
     ys[4] = quar2_y;
     xs[5] = pt2_x;
     ys[5] = pt2_y;

     Polygon p = new Polygon(xs, ys, 6); // create the new polygon with the 6 points
     Area clip = new Area(p);
     a.intersect(clip);
    Ellipse2D.Double inner = new Ellipse2D.Double(x + innerXOffset, y + innerYOffset, width - innerXOffset * 2, height - innerYOffset * 2);
    a.subtract(new Area(inner));
    return a;
}
```